# How to use my budget_amt found in my first function in the other functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, encoding, spyder

how do I get the code to use my budget_amt obtained in the set_budget function into other functions? I tried using global even though it is not advised which worked for the first code.  I have issues using the return function. I am not sure how to get my budget amount to be used in my new_transaction function. I am new to coding and racking my brains on how to get this done. Help, please!

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def set_budget():
    global budget_amt
    try:
        budget_amt=float(input("Please enter a budget amount for your monthly expenditure:\n$"))
        if budget_amt<=0:
            budget_amt=float(input("Please enter a positive value:\n$"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry! You Probably entered an invalid number or letter(s). Please enter a number:\n$")
        budget_amt=float(input("Please enter a budget amount for your monthly expenditure:"))
    confirmation1=input(f"Are you sure you want to set a monthly budget of ${budget_amt} ? \n[Y/N]:")
    if confirmation1.lower()=='y':
        print(f"Your have set a monthly budget of ${budget_amt}.")
        #add to file username, budget amt
    elif confirmation1.lower()=='n':
        set_budget()
    else:
        confirmation1=input(f"Are you sure you want to set a monthly budget of ${budget_amt}? \n[Y/N]:")
        if confirmation1.lower()=='y':
            print(f"Your have set a monthly budget of ${budget_amt}.")
            #add to file username, budget amt
        elif confirmation1.lower()=='n':
            set_budget()
    def set_warning():
        global warning_value
        limit_choice=input("Would you like to set a warning when a certain amount of your budget has been spent? \n[Y/N]:")
        if limit_choice.lower()=='y':
            print(f"You have previously set a monthly budget of ${budget_amt}.")
            try:
                warning_value=float(input("Please enter the amount at which you would like to receive a warning at:\n$"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number")
                warning_value=float(input("Please enter the amount at which you would like to receive a warning at:\n$"))
            confirmation2=input(f"You will receive a warning when your total monthly expenditure reaches ${warning_value}. Are you sure?\n [Y/N]:")
            if confirmation2.lower()=='n':
                set_warning()
            elif confirmation2.lower()=='y':
                print(f"You will receive a warning when your total monthly expenditure reaches ${warning_value}.")
                #add to csv file (warning_value)
            elif confirmation2.lower()!='n' or 'y':
                confirmation2=input(f"You will receive a warning when your total monthly expenditure reaches ${warning_value}. Are you sure?\n [Y/N]:")
        elif limit_choice.lower()=='n':
            confirmation3=input("Are you sure?\n [Y/N]:")
            if confirmation3.lower()=='n':
                set_warning()
            elif confirmation3.lower()=='y':
                print("You have chosen not to set a warning value.")
                warning_value=0
        elif limit_choice.lower()!='y' or 'n':
                set_warning()
        return warning_value
    set_warning()
    return budget_amt

set_budget()

def new_transaction():
    nonlocal budget_amt
    print("New Transaction")
    date = datetime.today()

    data = []
    try:
        transaction_amt = float(input("Please enter the transaction amount:\n$ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        transaction_amt = float(input("Please enter the transaction amount:\n$ "))
    choice = input("Is this an Income or Expense?\n [I/E]")
    if choice.lower() == "i":
        category = "Income"
        remarks = "NA"
        confirmation = input("Are you sure you want to input this transaction?\n [Y/N]: ")
        while confirmation.lower() != 'y':
            print("Transaction has been cancelled.")
            new_transaction()
        print("You have successfully entered the transaction.")
        
    if choice.lower() == "e":
        print("""
List of available categories:
Dining
Grocery
Entertainment
Others
""")
        category = input("Please type the category from the list above: ")
        remarks = input("Remarks if any, else put NA: ")
        confirmation = input("Are you sure you want to input this transaction? [Y/N]: ")
        while confirmation.lower() != 'y':
            print("Transaction has been cancelled.")
            new_transaction()
        while budget_amt >= 0:
            if transaction_amt > budget_amt:
                print("You have exceeded the budget")
            else :
                budget_amt -= transaction_amt
                print("You have successfully entered the transaction.")
                print("Balance remaining: ", budget_amt)
                
        print("You have no budget left for the month.")
    
    data.append([date,budget_amt, transaction_amt,remarks,category])
    storeValuesAsDF(data)
    return data

def storeValuesAsDF(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Username','Date', 'Budget', 'Final Amount', 'Remarks', 'Category'])
    saveAsCSV(df)
    return
    
def saveAsCSV(df):
    df.index += 1
    df.to_csv(index=True)
```

ALL THIS BELOW IS FILLER FOR ME TO POST SORRY FOR THE INCONVENIENCE
Python is a multi-paradigm programming language. Object-oriented programming and structured programming are fully supported, and many of its features support functional programming and aspect-oriented programming (including by metaprogramming[57] and metaobjects (magic methods)).[58] Many other paradigms are supported via extensions, including design by contract[59][60] and logic programming.[61]

Python uses dynamic typing and a combination of reference counting and a cycle-detecting garbage collector for memory management.[62] It also features dynamic name resolution (late binding), which binds method and variable names during program execution.

Python's design offers some support for functional programming in the Lisp tradition. It has filter,mapandreduce functions; list comprehensions, dictionaries, sets, and generator expressions.[63] The standard library has two modules (itertools and functools) that implement functional tools borrowed from Haskell and Standard ML.[64]

The language's core philosophy is summarized in the document The Zen of Python (PEP 20), which includes aphorisms such as:[65]

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Readability counts.
Rather than having all of its functionality built into its core, Python was designed to be highly extensible (with modules). This compact modularity has made it particularly popular as a means of adding programmable interfaces to existing applications. Van Rossum's vision of a small core language with a large standard library and easily extensible interpreter stemmed from his frustrations with ABC, which espoused the opposite approach.[38]

Python strives for a simpler, less-cluttered syntax and grammar while giving developers a choice in their coding methodology. In contrast to Perl's "there is more than one way to do it" motto, Python embraces a "there should be one— and preferably only one —obvious way to do it" design philosophy.[65] Alex Martelli, a Fellow at the Python Software Foundation and Python book author, writes that "To describe something as 'clever' is not considered a compliment in the Python culture."[66]

Python's developers strive to avoid premature optimization, and reject patches to non-critical parts of the CPython reference implementation that would offer marginal increases in speed at the cost of clarity.[67] When speed is important, a Python programmer can move time-critical functions to extension modules written in languages such as C, or use PyPy, a just-in-time compiler. Cython is also available, which translates a Python script into C and makes direct C-level API calls into the Python interpreter.

Python's developers aim for the language to be fun to use. This is reflected in its name—a tribute to the British comedy group Monty Python[68]—and in occasionally playful approaches to tutorials and reference materials, such as examples that refer to spam and eggs (a reference to a Monty Python sketch) instead of the standard foo and bar.[69][70]

A common neologism in the Python community is pythonic, which can have a wide range of meanings related to program style. To say that code is pythonic is to say that it uses Python idioms well, that it is natural or shows fluency in the language, that it conforms with Python's minimalist philosophy and emphasis on readability. In contrast, code that is difficult to understand or reads like a rough transcription from another programming language is called unpythonic.[71][72]

Users and admirers of Python, especially those considered knowledgeable or experienced, are often referred to as Pythonistas.[73][74]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you posting filler? Please stop.

Okay --

A program (or a piece of software) has different parts; and we can think of a useful distinction: it has a **state**, which is the collection of things that it knows about, and a part of that state is **instructions** (or function definitions): when this happens, do that.

But none of the above *do* anything automatically, they just sit there being rules/information.

Separately, you also need to tell the program to *do* things, by calling those functions.

So, definition:

```
def do_stuff():
    print("doing something")
    return("printed")
```

When called, this function will print a line ("doing something"), and return a value ("printed"). But in order for that to happen, you have to call the function, and, assign the 'return value' to a variable. Note that you did so in your function with this line:

```
category = input("Please type the category from the list above: ")
```

You are *calling* the function 'input', and assigning it's return value to the variable 'category'. So, you need to do something similar with your function in order to capture its return value:

```
budget_amt = set_budget()
```

This creates a variable in your programs state, budget_amt, which contains the value returned by the function set_budget. Second, how do we use this in another place? There are two ways: one, we define that as a 'global variable', which means everything else in the state can see that variable. This is considered bad form, however, because it makes debugging and maintaining your code very difficult -- though it is still sometimes the right choice.

Much more commonly, we want to *pass variables* as arguments *into* functions.

```
def do_stuff(budget):
    budget = budget - transaction
    return budget

new_budget = do_stuff(budget_amt)
```

So, first we create the rule (the function definition): pass one variable (the current budget), subtract a transaction amount, and then return the new budget.

Second, we actually call that, by passing in `budget_amt` that we created above (and capturing the result in `new_budget`, which we could use later on, and so forth.

So, think about your functions: what variables should you be passing into the functions, and how are you capturing the returns from those functions?

I think you would benefit from following a basic tutorial, which will cover a lot of these basics. Perhaps: [Python 3 Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)